# Capture Verbose out from Powershell function

Tags: powershell, logging, verbosity, powershell-module

I am attempting to call a Powershell function from another Powershell function. The function I am calling has a lot of verbose output and I need to capture them to a file. Since I am calling said function multiple times, I need the verbose outputs appended to the end of the file.

I attempted the following

```
Invoke-TeardownWorkflow -WorkflowID $i -PostTeardownAction=@{$IPList[$i]="Reconnect-PrimaryNetwork"} 9 >>C:\TeardownLog.log
```

However, the code didn't work as expected and kept repeating

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '9'.
```

The function is source-controlled (so, I can't touch the function.). Also these functions are all part of `PSM1` files. The Teardown.log file has some entries prior to the execution of the code mentioned above.

Comment: ...Well, what is the `9` doing there?

Comment: try using `*` instead of `9`. @arco444 9 is supposed to be the combined output, allthough i can´t find this in about_redirection (maybe its from an older version?)

Comment: 9 was accepted in v2, and has been replaced by * in more recent versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `4>`

```
Invoke-TeardownWorkflow -WorkflowID $i -PostTeardownAction=@{$IPList[$i]="Reconnect-PrimaryNetwork"} 4>C:\TeardownLog.log
```

More about redirection [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx), here is an extract:

```
4>        Sends verbose output to    Import-Module * -Verbose 4> Verbose.txt
          the specified file.

4>>       Appends verbose output     Import-Module * -Verbose 4>> Save-Verbose.txt
          to the contents of the 
          specified file.
```

Comment: Do you have an error? Is the file created? Did you try alternatives such as *>?

Comment: Yeah, the error was the same as for with 9 and * - `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '4'.` or `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '*'.`

Comment: Did you put a space between 4 and >? You shouldn't.